# RabbitMQ - Only consume failed queue messages that have a specific property/tag/key from a dead letter queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, message-queue, messaging

I have a queue that accepts different messages from multiple services.

When the processing of those messages fails on the consumer, I want to send a message back to the sender, telling him that it has failed and asking for a new new updated message (with the latest data).

Requeueing the failed messages will not work for this, because the order of the messages is vital (sequential updates to the same entity should be processed in the correct order, or a re-fetch of the data must happen).

I already have one dead letter queue for the queue, where I can send the failed messages.

But how can I make each consumer attached to that dead letter queue ONLY process the messages that are intended for him and and not all of the messages?

I see there is a mechanism for doing that with multiple queues and routing keys: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-dotnet.html

But I don't want to deal with many queues, because of the complexity of having many queues and because I feel that using many queues will require many dedicated threads on each service for reading those queues.

Is there a way to route messages coming from the same queue, to a specific consumer?
Or maybe broadcast the message to all of them and let each of them handle their own message?

I am thinking it like this: Mark the original message with a tag, send it, when it fails it gets sent in the dead letter queue while retaining the tag, then the correct consumer processes it.

Any code samples will be greatly appreciated. I use the C# libraries for RabbitMQ if that matters.